# Output a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

When I use `%p` format character in my `printf` statements to output the value of a pointer variable, it actually outputs hexadecimal? Why is this so?
How to output a pointer in my case?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(){

    char c1 = 'A';
    char c2 = c1;
    char *c3 = &c2;
    char *c4;
    char *c5;
    char c6;

    c4 = c3;
    c5 = &c1;
    c6 = &c3;

    c2 = 'Z';
    c3 = c5;

    printf(" %p", *c5);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Just write `printf(" %p", c5);`. Pointers are printed as hexadecimal numbers by default.

Comment: "it actually outputs hexadecimal? Why is this so?" – because your implementation of the standard library decided that pointers are printed in hexadecimal (for practical debugging reasons).

Comment: What do you have against hex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the value at the pointer use

```
printf("%c", *c5);
```

or if you want to print the address of the pointer in `decimal` system, use

```
printf("%u", c5);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple,try this:
address c5:
    printf("%d\n",c5);
c5 point address:
    printf("%d\n",&c5);
value:
    printf("%d\n",c5);